# Calling appropriate Exit method for current application from library?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, console-application, exit

I created a class library to AutoUpdate applications. It needs to kill the application when it finishes downloading the update. Currently, I determine the exit method to use by using below code.

```
if (Application.MessageLoop)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
else
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

I know that Environment.Exit(0) is a brutal way to kill the application and It doesn't kill the application when the application uses CefSharp. Is there any way I can call Application.Current.Shutdown() when the application is WPF?

If you didn't understand the question you can look at the issue and complete project using below URL.

https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET/issues/11

Comment: So why exactly you cannot call Application.Current.Shutdown?

Comment: @Evk  
The library uses WinForms and I need to call the Application.Current.Shutdown from the library if the main application using the library is WPF application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can call Application.Current.Shutdown() when the application is WPF?

Just check if there is any `Application` object available at runtime:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current != null) //if WPF
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

If `Application.Current` returns an `Application` object, you can assume that your code executes in the context of a WPF application and you could safely call the `Shutdown` method.

Comment: I'm getting type or namespace 'Application' doesn't exist in System.Window when I tried this.

Comment: I added the reference to PresentationFramework and WindowsBase and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put in `this.close();` in the WPF class

Comment: Code is in the class library so I don't think this.close() will work.